# Error in execution case when nvl in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, case, oracle-sqldeveloper, nvl

```sql
SELECT cast(ID as number) AS ID,
    cast(MARKETER_ID as NUMBER) AS MARKETER_ID,
    CAST(NEW_MARKETING_BANKS_ID AS NUMBER) AS NEW_MARKETING_BANKS_ID_ASSIGNE,
    To_char(To_date(REQUEST_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD','NLS_CALENDAR=''Gregorian''')) as  TARIKH_DARKHAST,
    NEW_MARKETING_BANKS_NAME,
    STATE,
    VIN AS SHASI,
    cast(SUBSCRIPTION_CODE as number) as ESHTERAKID,
    PRODUCT_NAME,
    MARKETING_GROUP,
    PERSON_TYPE,
    TO_DATE_STR,
  case when NVL(SUBSTR(FROM_DATE,1,10) = 'NULL' then (select max(TARIKHIJAD),ESHTERAKID FROM QV_JOZEAT_RIALI_FROSH GROUP BY TARIKHIJAD,ESHTERAKID))
    else (SUBSTR(FROM_DATE,1,10) end AS TARIKH_ENGHEZA,
    IS_IKE,
    CANCELABLE,
    CAST(MARKETING_GROUP_ID AS NUMBER) AS MARKETING_GROUP_ID
    
FROM WH.VIW_WH_MARKETING_ASSIGNEE where (PERSON_ID is not null) 
and (MARKETER_ID is not null) AND (SUBSCRIPTION_CODE IS NOT NULL) and (REQUEST_DATE is not null)

> ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments



SELECT 
    CAST(NEW_MARKETING_BANKS_ID AS NUMBER) AS NEW_MARKETING_BANKS_ID_ASSIGNE,
    To_char(To_date(REQUEST_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD','NLS_CALENDAR=''Gregorian''')) as  TARIKH_DARKHAST,
    STATE,
    cast(SUBSCRIPTION_CODE as number) as ESHTERAKID,
    PRODUCT_NAME,
    MARKETING_GROUP,
    PERSON_TYPE,
    TO_DATE_STR,
-- Note below CASE
case when NVL(SUBSTR(FROM_DATE,1,10) = 'NULL' then (select max(TARIKHIJAD),ESHTERAKID FROM QV_JOZEAT_RIALI_FROSH GROUP BY TARIKHIJAD,ESHTERAKID))
else (SUBSTR(FROM_DATE,1,10) end AS TARIKH_ENGHEZA
  
--
FROM WH.VIW_WH_MARKETING_ASSIGNEE where (PERSON_ID is not null) 
and (MARKETER_ID is not null) AND (SUBSCRIPTION_CODE IS NOT NULL) and (REQUEST_DATE is not null) ;
```

Comment: Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Comment: My question was the error in using case when

Comment: You nvl doesn’t have a second argument, or a closing parenthesis. I guess it should `nvl(substr(…), ‘NULL’) = …` but why not just check for null directly?

Comment: The nvl argument selects a replacement for each field. I want the case when (NVL to use a query with another select to replace in NVL.

for example:
case when (NVL(SUBSTR(FROM_DATE,1,10)), then (select max(date_modif),ID FROM QV_JOZEAT_RIALI_FROSH GROUP BY date_modif,ID))
else (SUBSTR(FROM_DATE,1,10) end AS exp_date,

Comment: I try this:
 (NVL(SUBSTR(FROM_DATE,1,10), (select max(TARIKHIJAD) FROM QV_JOZEAT_RIALI_FROSH GROUP BY ESHTERAKID)) )

and answer was:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row error iz caused by your sql (from the question code)

```sql
select max(TARIKHIJAD),ESHTERAKID FROM QV_JOZEAT_RIALI_FROSH GROUP BY TARIKHIJAD,ESHTERAKID
```

If you use aggregate function on one column [ max(TARIKHIJAD) ] and do the grouping on the same column you will get all the different rows and not the Max one.
Lets suppose that your data looks like this:

| TARIKHIJAD | ESHTERAKID |
| --- | --- |
| 01-OCT-22 | AAA |
| 15-OCT-22 | BBB |
| 16-OCT-22 | AAA |
| 28-OCT-22 | AAA |

The above sql will result like below:

```sql
select max(TARIKHIJAD),ESHTERAKID FROM QV_JOZEAT_RIALI_FROSH GROUP BY TARIKHIJAD,ESHTERAKID
--  R e s u l t :
--  MAX(TARIKHIJAD) ESHTERAKID
--  --------------- ----------
--  16-OCT-22       AAA        
--  01-OCT-22       AAA        
--  28-OCT-22       AAA        
--  15-OCT-22       BBB
```

In your comment you have corrected this but there is still the same error because it looks like here:

```sql
select max(TARIKHIJAD) FROM QV_JOZEAT_RIALI_FROSH GROUP BY ESHTERAKID
--  MAX(TARIKHIJAD)
--  --------------- --> needs filtering 
--  15-OCT-22       --> this one is for 'BBB' 
--  28-OCT-22       --> this one is for 'AAA'
```

If this select statement is after THEN keyword in CASE expression **it should result in one and only one value**. The same rule stands if it is within Nvl function as the 2nd argument. In either case you want to assign a value to the column under certain condition.
This means that you have to filter the resulting value.
What you need would look something like here:

```sql
-- 1.
...
CASE WHEN FROM_DATE Is Null Then (select max(TARIKHIJAD),ESHTERAKID FROM QV_JOZEAT_RIALI_FROSH WHERE ESHTERAKID = 'BBB' GROUP BY ESHTERAKID) ELSE FROM_DATE END
...
-- or 2.
...
Nvl(FROM_DATE, (select max(TARIKHIJAD),ESHTERAKID FROM QV_JOZEAT_RIALI_FROSH WHERE ESHTERAKID = 'AAA' GROUP BY ESHTERAKID))
...
```

Expression like NVL(SUBSTR(FROM_DATE,1,10)) is wrong primarily because if FROM_DATE is null then it is null and  any substring within will be null too - meaning that SUBSTR does not do anything. It should be just NVL(FROM_DATE, some_value).
Regards...